# Configure two separate websites having one as a child of another

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I'm configuring a IIS 7.5 on which I want to have 2 different websites (so that I can have different publishing profiles in Visual Studio).

The thing is, I've search around and can't find a way to make things work as I want them to.

So, I have, let's say, Site1 which is located at www.site1.com.
Then I want to have Site2, by configuring it as a site in IIS, but have it available at www.site1.com/site2.

How can I achieve this? Is this even possible?

Creating an application inside the site1 site won't let me create a specific publish profile, in order to have everything separated, since these 2 sites are two different projects on VS.

Any help please?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two sites and one application on the first site using the [WebAdministration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) Powershell Module.

```
New-WebSite -Name Site1 -port 80 -HostHeader www.site1.com  -PhysicalPath "C:\inetpub\Site1"
New-WebSite -Name Site2 -port 80 -HostHeader www.site2.com  -PhysicalPath "C:\inetpub\Site2"
New-WebApplication -Name site2 -Site Site1 -PhysicalPath "C:\inetpub\Site2"
```

Site2 is then accessible via `www.site1.com/site2` and `www.site2.com`

The key is to point the second site and the application to the same physical path.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted :D. Just didn't know how to achieve it (but hey.. I'm a programmer, not a system guy). Thank you for you help @Peter Hahndorf

Comment: I have one more question regarding this matter: If I have a VS Solution with a project that comprises (what should be) two different sites, and I separate them into different sites in IIS, using that method posted on the previous answer, will the application in the virtual directory inherit the "main" application web.config or will it need it's own web.config?

Comment: @Zed_Blade - In general all IIS child objects (applications, virtual directories, normal folders) inherit settings from the web.config at the root level (site). Usually you still want a web.config in your child object to add new settings or override existing ones from the root level.

Comment: Thank you @Peter. After reading your answer I managed to understand why I was getting errors with duplicate entries and how to stop inheritance. Really helpful :) <br /> I can't upvote for now, but you'll get my votes once I'm allowed to